# R - shiny - addPolygons must be called with both lng and lat, or with neither

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to ask for some help here. 
I have my polygon shapefile and I would like to display it trough leaflet in R-shiny. However, I keep having the result: Error: addPolygons must be called with both lng and lat, or with neither.

I already tried with sp package and sf package (following whit link: https://community.rstudio.com/t/projection-problems-with-leaflet/27747/5), and changed the CRS also with both packages. Outside from shiny it works fine, but inside of it is just not working.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)

wo <-readOGR("SHAPES/world/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp", layer = "ne_50m_admin_0_countries")
wt <- spTransform(wo, CRS("+proj=longlat +init=epsg:4326 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))


ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("mytitle"),

        mainPanel(
           leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = 600)
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
       leaflet(wt) %>%
            addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
            addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", group = "CartoDB")%>%
            addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "ESRI")%>%
            setView(lng= -78.49511705 , lat = -1.47200601, zoom = 5)%>%
            addMiniMap(tiles = providers$CartoDB.Positron,
                        toggleDisplay = TRUE) %>%
            addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OpenstreetMap", "CartoDB", "ESRI"))%>%
            addPolygons(color = "white", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5, 
                        opacity = 1,0, fillOpacity = 0.5
                        #dashArray = "3",
                         #highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "grey", weight =2, 
                         #bringToFront = TRUE)
                        )
               })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also tried to display the variable inside the addPolygons, like this:

```
addPolygons(data = wt, color = "white", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5, 
                        opacity = 1,0, fillOpacity = 0.5
                        #dashArray = "3",
                         #highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "grey", weight =2, 
                         #bringToFront = TRUE)
                        )
```

Could somebody give any glimpse of what is happening here, please

Answer (score 0):

In the addPolygons instead of data = wt , try using data = wt ().